# add data from Android-notification to Android-App

Tags: android, gcc, xamarin, notifications, azure-notificationhub

I'm using Xamarin - Visual Studio 15 for Android.

I'm sending Notification to my App, using Azure Service Bus and Google Cloud Messaging.

Everything works fine.
Now, I would like that - every time that notification arrives - if the app running (or running in the background) - the App will collect the information from the notification.

The structure of the application:

The Activity Class:

```
using ...

namespace qtosof
{
    [Activity (MainLauncher = true, Icon="@drawable/ic_launcher", Label="@string/app_name", Theme="@style/AppTheme")]
    public class ToDoActivity : Activity
    {
        static ToDoActivity instance = new ToDoActivity();

        public static ToDoActivity CurrentActivity
        {
            get { return instance; }
        }
        #endregion

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Activity_To_Do);
            instance = this;

            Button setEmail = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.setButt);
            EditText editMail = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editMail);
            setEmail.Click += delegate
            {
                string temp = editMail.Text;
                GcmConnect(temp);
                setEmail.Enabled = false;
            };
        }

        public void GcmConnect(string uniqeMail)
        {
            string getUniqeEmailUser = uniqeMail; 
            string getAndroidId = Android.Provider.Settings.Secure.GetString(Android.App.Application.Context.ContentResolver, Android.Provider.Settings.Secure.AndroidId);
            userData.SetUniqeData(getUniqeEmailUser, getAndroidId);

            try
            {
                GcmClient.CheckDevice(this);
                GcmClient.CheckManifest(this);
                GcmClient.Register(this, ToDoBroadcastReceiver.senderIDs);
            }
            catch
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("The device has Problem to Register GcmClient.", "PROBLEM!");   
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The

```
using...

[assembly: Permission(Name = "XXXXXX.XXXXXX.permission.C2D_MESSAGE")]
[assembly: UsesPermission(Name = "XXXXXX.XXXXXX.permission.C2D_MESSAGE")]
[assembly: UsesPermission(Name = "com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE")]
[assembly: UsesPermission(Name = "android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS")]
[assembly: UsesPermission(Name = "android.permission.INTERNET")]
[assembly: UsesPermission(Name = "android.permission.WAKE_LOCK")]

[BroadcastReceiver(Permission = Gcm.Client.Constants.PERMISSION_GCM_INTENTS)]
[IntentFilter(new string[] { Gcm.Client.Constants.INTENT_FROM_GCM_MESSAGE }, Categories = new string[] { "XXXXXX.XXXXXX" })]
[IntentFilter(new string[] { Gcm.Client.Constants.INTENT_FROM_GCM_REGISTRATION_CALLBACK }, Categories = new string[] { "XXXXXX.XXXXXX" })]
[IntentFilter(new string[] { Gcm.Client.Constants.INTENT_FROM_GCM_LIBRARY_RETRY }, Categories = new string[] { "XXXXXX.XXXXXX" })]

public class ToDoBroadcastReceiver : GcmBroadcastReceiverBase<PushHandlerService>
{
    public static string[] senderIDs = new string[] { "XXXXXXXXXXXX" };
}


[Service] 
public class PushHandlerService : GcmServiceBase
{

    public static int numOfQue = 1;

    private NotificationHub Hub { get; set; }

    public PushHandlerService() : base(ToDoBroadcastReceiver.senderIDs){}

    protected override void OnRegistered(Context context, string registrationId)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("The device has been registered with GCM.", "Success!");


        string connectionString = "Endpoint=sb://XXXXXXXXXXXX.XXXXXXXXXXXX.XXXXXXXXXXXX.XXXXXX/;SharedAccessKeyName=XXXXXXXXXXXX;SharedAccessKey=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
        string notificationHubPath = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
        Hub = new NotificationHub(notificationHubPath, connectionString, context);        

        try
        {
            Hub.UnregisterAll(registrationId);
        }
        catch
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("The device has Problem to UnregisterAll.", "PROBLEM!");            
        }


        string EmailTag = userData.GetUniqeData(); // get the uniqe Id from User login data, For example - let's say that the user e-mail is unique
        string AndroidTag = userData.GetUniqeData("AndroidId");
        var tags = new List<string>() { EmailTag, AndroidTag };  

        try
        {
            var hubRegistration = Hub.Register(registrationId, tags.ToArray());
        }
        catch 
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("The device has Problem to Register.", "PROBLEM!");                        
        }
    }

    protected override void OnMessage(Context context, Intent intent)
    {

        //TODO... all is work fine

    }

    protected override void OnUnRegistered(Context context, string registrationId)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    protected override void OnError(Context context, string errorId)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(
            string.Format("Error occurred in the notification: {0}.", errorId));
    }

}
```

I thought to use a static variable, but I'm not sure that's it's the right way...

Thanks for your time